# How can i resolve bitcode error while archiving build .IPA file?

Tags: objective-c, bitcode

When I build an .IPA file for testing, I get the following error...how to resolve this.

```
2016-06-23 06:51:30 +0000 [MT] Presenting: Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "Failed to verify bitcode in MBCircularProgressBar.framework/MBCircularProgressBar:
error: Bundle only contains bitcode-marker /var/folders/w1/59sf4qyj2wzdtd_8wb24bcfh0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.jB3/Roo…" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to verify bitcode in MBCircularProgressBar.framework/MBCircularProgressBar:
error: Bundle only contains bitcode-marker /var/folders/w1/59sf4qyj2wzdtd_8wb24bcfh0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.jB3/Roo…}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For iOS apps, bitcode is the default, but optional.

If you provide bitcode, all apps and frameworks in the app bundle need to include bitcode.

**NOTE : For watchOS apps, bitcode is required.**

I think "**MBCircularProgressBar.framework**" was compiled without bitcode.  but the bitcode option is enabled in your project settings.

Try this :

Go to `your Project` --> `Target` --> `Build Settings` --> Set `NO` to `Enable Bitcode`

And then retry to build.

Thank you @NSNOOB for providing image. It will provide more clearification of above steps.

[image]